# Cambio de Formulario en C#

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo cambiar de un formulario? Estoy tratando de usar:

```
this.Hide();
adminPanel1 admin_pan = new adminPanel1();
admin_pan.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

pero `adminpanel1` lleva parámetros :

```
   public adminPanel1(string NOM_USUARIO)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
```

¿Entonces no me deja usar esos métodos que podría hacer?

> error : CS7036 c#

Comment: `adminPanel1 admin_pan = new adminPanel1("nombre");`. Por otro lado, te seguirá dando error. Si muestras el nuevo formulario con `ShowDialog`, no te va a permitir cerrar el formulario que lo llama.